# How to remember order of the serialization protocol `dump()` function's arguments?

Tags: python

In Python, we have a kind of serialization protocol, consisting of 4 functions or methods:

```
load(stream): deserialize from stream
loads(str): deserialize from string
dump(obj, stream): serialize to stream
dumps(obj): serialize to string (returned)
```

These are used for JSON, pickles and probably other kinds of protocols I can't think of right now, and I really like it as a simple abstraction. However, I can seemingly never remember the order of the `dump()` arguments. Does anyone have a good hint or mnemonic device to help me remember this?

(I realize this isn't really a standard Stack Overflow question. Still, I believe this kind of thing is a valid problem for many programmers in many context, and I've been running into this one for years. I also reviewed the rules for Stack Overflow vs the Programmers StackExchange, which led me to believe Stack Overflow would be a slightly better fit. I also think the answer and comment so far have been helpful, there hasn't been any argument or extended discussion. Therefore, I would plead to reopen this question.)

Comment: dump object into garbage can, not carbage can into object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dump a stone object in the river stream!

i.e.: dump *what* in *where* and not dump *where* in *what*